# Why/if separation of variables gives all eigenvalues of Hamiltonian for Hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

I'm self-studying QM through Griffith's book. I have a question on the time-independent Schrödinger equation with Coulomb's potential energy. The Schrödinger equation was solved to rediscover the Bohr energy formula:
\begin{equation}
E_n \propto \frac{1}{n^2}, n=1,2,...
\end{equation}
The equation was solved by separation of variables. My question is why/if this method can give all energy levels (eigenvalues) of the Hamiltonian?

In other words, the eigenfunctions $\psi_{nlm}$ obtained by separation of variables are simultaneous eigenvectors of the following three operators
\begin{equation*}
L_z \\
L^2\\
H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V(r)
\end{equation*}
So why/if the corresponding eigenvalues (of $H$):
\begin{equation*}
H \psi_{nlm}= E_n \psi_{nlm}
\end{equation*}
are all possible eigenvalues of $H$?

Comment: But it is possible to have other eigenfunctions. Say, if you choose $L_x$ rather than $L_z$, but you can express $L_x$ eigenfunctions with superpositions of $L_z$ ones. Griffiths already did cover that, did it not?

Comment: *why $H$ itself does not contain other possible eigenvalues/eigenfunctions?* Did your textbook also derive the unbound wavefunctions?

Comment: Are you asking why **all** the eigenfunctions for $H$ are also eigenfunctions of $L^2$ and $L_z$?

Comment: I guess what I meant is why the Bohr formula give all possible energy levels. Those are the eigenvalues corresponding to the simultaneous eigenfunctions of three operators.

Comment: To John Rennie: that's exactly what I'm asking. Thanks!

Comment: Also, this is not actually the magic of separation of variables yet. For example, $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$ variables are actually intermingled in the spherical harmonics $Y^\ell_m$. Instead, what you have is a _maximal set of observables commuting with the Hamiltonian operator._

Comment: To naturallyInconsistent: I guess that's exactly what I get confused. I understand that those eigenfunctions are for a maximal set of observables commuting with the Hamiltonian. But if we are only interested in the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian themselves, why there cannot be other possible values?

Comment: Hi@Victor. Welcome to Phys.SE. To reopen this post (v3) consider to align question in title and body.

Comment: An eigenfunction for $H$ is not necessarily an eigenfunction for $L_z$ because the spectrum is degenerate.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thank you for the suggestion! I've modified the question. Please see if it needs further clarification.

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/726679/justifying-separation-of-variables-in-solving-the-schr%c3%b6dinger-equation-in-3d) might help. Although it should be noted that the bound states of the hydrogen atom do not form a complete orthonormal basis.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Many thanks! Can I take it as: it is a sophisticated math problem involving advanced PDE theory or funtional analysis lol?

Comment: Yes, it is complicated in general. Similar questions were also asked on MathSE, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166117/completeness-of-solutions-and-the-separation-of-variables-method) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163773/when-does-separation-of-variables-yield-basis-of-solution-set). Anyway, we have some mathematical physicists in our community here, which might leave a helpful answer to your (good) question.